# Synth Look and Feel - Is it possible to write xml to do both general and specified customization?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, synth

Synth provides a way to use xml to customize java swing look and feel. From my understanding, it could do general customization. For example:

- General **JButton**: set its font, background, foreground ... to all buttons (synth could do this)
- but i also have a specified **MyButton** on my specified GUI (suppose in com.jasons.MyPanel), i want it has a different font, background from general Jbutton.

So does synth xml support this (and how)? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Synth L&F supports also name-binding.

Here is the XML example:

```
<style id="defaultHeaderPanel">
    <insets top="4" left="4" bottom="4" right="4"/>
    <state>
        <opaque value="true" />
        <color type="BACKGROUND" value="#00538c"/>
    </state>
</style>
<bind style="defaultHeaderPanel" type="name" key="DefaultHeaderPanel" />
```

To use this style you need to call the method `setName(String)` with the `key` of your `bind` XML element.

For example:

```
public class HeaderPanel extends JPanel {

    public HeaderPanel() {
        setName("DefaultHeaderPanel"); // assign style name
    }
}
```